# Kanji characters in utf-8

Tags: python, unicode, utf-8

```
>>> s='未作評級'
>>> s
'\xe6\x9c\xaa\xe4\xbd\x9c\xe8\xa9\x95\xe7\xb4\x9a'
>>> s = unicode(s)
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xe6 in position 0: ordinal not in range(128)
```

How would I get the `未作評級` into uniciode?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Either use a Unicode string from the start:

```
>>> s = u'未作評級'
```

or *decode* the string from its current encoding (which appears to be UTF-8). Then you get a Unicode string.

```
>>> s = '未作評級'.decode("utf-8")
```